# Understanding behavior of program

Tags: c

I'm running the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
static void threadStart(void (*function)(void), void* arg) {
    // schedules thread in Queue
    function(void* arg);
}
```

The compiler giving me two errors:

```
In function ‘threadStart’:
sample.c:5:11: error: expected expression before ‘void’
 function(void* arg);
       ^
 sample.c:5:11: error: too many arguments to function ‘function’
```

How pass a function to run with a given argument without raising errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had started to write-up an answer, that I just deleted that suggested this is what you wanted:

```
static void threadStart(void (*function)(void*), void* arg) {
    // schedules thread in Queue
    function(arg);
}
```

But then I looked at what you are trying to do with a function pointer, that nearly resembles a `pthread_create` start routine.

So it didn't make sense that you've got a function called `threadStart` that neither starts a thread nor appears to be the start routine for a thread.  I could be wrong, because we don't see anything else in your code that suggests how `threadStart` is invoked.

So I was wondering if this is what you really meant, a function to be run within a thread:

```
void* threadStart(void* arg)
{
    someOtherCodeOrFunction(arg); // your code goes here
}
```

And you meant to instantiate that thread to run that above function with `arg` as the parameter value:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadStart, arg);
```